# Compare Kinect and Vicon Data

Tags: kinect, autoencoder

I have a Kinect and a Vicon system, data from Kinect comes at 30Hz while in Vicon it comes at ~120Hz. The system is capturing the same person. Also, the features per timestep in Kinect and Vicon is different. Vicon having more features. Is there a way to bring them at the same level. Will Autoencoding both to same lower dimensional features make them suitable for equating?

Answer (score 0):

If you have them synchronized you can just duplicate the data of kinect x 4 for each frame. If not you need to synchronize them firstly by using a lighting flash for example and check the appearance and disappearance of the light.